# Pass a javascript function parameter to a jsp if-else condition

Tags: javascript, jsp, if-statement

In a checkout processus of a webapp, a javascript function is called when choosing a payment method. I need to implement a separate pending view, that the user sees when he chooses PayPal as a payment method; when choosing another payment method, the user sees another pending view.

This is the javascript function:

```
    function fillMethodData(methodId, _cbFunc) {
        methodNode = document.getElementById(methodId);
        shopallmethods.cb_fillMethodData(_cbFunc, 
        methodNode.getAttribute('data-method'),     
        methodNode.getAttribute('data-provider'), 
        methodNode.getAttribute('data-brand'));
     }
```

when the case methodId is equal the parameter methodDataPP (PayPal), 
I need another view then in the other cases. I know by checking with an if-condition in Javascript, that the parameter is right:

```
if (methodId === "methodDataPP") {
            var PayPal = methodId;
            console.log(PayPal);        
        }
```

This is my JSP if-condition:

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${param.fillMethodData.methodDataPP == 'true'}">
     <c:form action="/shop_pending_paypal" name="ShopEnterForm" method="POST">
     <input type="hidden" name="platin" value="<f:equal property="variant"  
          value="platin">true</f:equal><f:notEqual 
          property="variant" value="platin">false</f:notEqual>" />
        <c:mark name="choosemethod" />
    </c:form>
</c:when>
<c:otherwise>
<c:form action="/shop_pending" name="ShopEnterForm" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="platin" value="<f:equal 
         property="variant" value="platin">true</f:equal><f:notEqual 
         property="variant" value="platin">false</f:notEqual>" />
         <c:mark name="choosemethod" />
    </c:form>
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

It is not working until now. I would appreciate any help on this, thanks a lot!

Comment: I didn't get it... When do you want to put your Javascript function inside your JSP file? Do you want to call javascript function `fillMethodData` depending on the result of your JSP *when test*  ?

Comment: Thanks for putting effort into this - no, it´s the other way round: The function comes first. When the passed methodId is equal to methodDataPP, then the first condition of the JSP-part should be executed, the first view called. If not, then the other view should be called.

Comment: So, the user are brownsing, then, it loads a page in the browser, then, he clicks in some button and a javascript function is called to a view to PayPal or another generic view? I'm asking because I want to have a overview of the scenario...

Comment: Due to recent new requirements to the project, the coding problem is now different; A JSP if-else-statement should no longer be used. Instead, the solution should be pure Javascript. Thank you for putting effort into this.